# Vb.net how to get Time data from access?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I want to get the work hour schedule for employees to show up in the labels of a form.
The input will be = IDdeEmpleado "Employee ID" and Fecha "Date" and it should get Horadecomienzodetrabajo "Start"and horadeConclusiondeTrabajo "Finish".

This is the code I have so far 
     'the query:

```
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Horario] WHERE [IddeEmpleado] = @Id AND [Fecha] = @Fecha ", myConnection)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", txtEmpID.Text)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha", SqlDbType.Date).Value = lblDate.Text


    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

    Dim HoradeEntrada As String = ""
    Dim HoradeSalida As String = ""

    'if found:

    Try

        HoradeEntrada = dr("HoradeComienzodeTrabajo")
        HoradeSalida = dr("HoradeConclusiondeTrabajo")

        lblComienzo.Text = HoradeEntrada
        lblTermina.Text = HoradeSalida

    Catch
        MsgBox("Sorry,No Hay Horario para el ID Entrado", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Invalid ID")

    End Try
```

Comment: So what's the actual problem? Is an exception being thrown? If so, try looking at the exception rather than ignoring it and displaying your own error message that may or may not have anything to do with the issue.

Comment: my problem is I get a date and not the time

Comment: What is the data type of your `HoradeComienzodeTrabajo` and `HoradeConclusiondeTrabajo` columns?

Comment: date/time is the data type

Comment: Then you should not be assigning the values directly to `String` variables for one thing. You should be assigning them to `DateTime` variables in your VB code first and then, at the very least, you can look at the values in their native form and then go form there.  If those `DateTime` values have their time portion set to zero then there's no time values in the database to begin with, so there's nothing you can do in your retrieval code to fix that.  In that case, it would be your saving code that's the issue.

Comment: ok, i will check that out. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several important changes in here:

```
Using myConnection As New OleDbConnection("connection string here"), _
      cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Horario] WHERE [IddeEmpleado] = ? AND [Fecha] = ?", myConnection)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", txtEmpID.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fecha", OleDbType.Date).Value = CDate(lblDate.Text)

    myConnection.Open()
    Using dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
       If dr.Read() Then
           lblComienzo.Text = CDate(dr("HoradeComienzodeTrabajo")).ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff")
           lblTermina.Text = CDate(dr("HoradeConclusiondeTrabajo")).ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff")
       Else
           MsgBox("Sorry,No Hay Horario para el ID Entrado", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Invalid ID")
       End If
       dr.Close()
    End Using
End Using
```

Most of this stands alone, but I do need to explain one thing. Do *NOT* try to re-use the same connection object (like `myConnection`) throughout your app. ADO.Net is built with a feature called "Connection Pooling" in mind, and all the major providers (including OleDb) support this. With Connection Pooling, re-using the same connection object works against you. It's likely to make your app *slower*, because database access will become a choke point and interfere with the built-in pooling.

Instead, you really should create a new connection object for most calls into the database.

Also note the change to SQL string. OleDb uses `?` as the parameter placeholder, rather than named `@` parameters, and matches the ADO.Net parameter object to the placeholder in the SQL string based on position in the string and positions in the parameters collection on the OleDbCommand.

Comment: I used this solution but I get this Comienzo Turno = 12/30/1899

Comment: What I want to display is time and not date

Comment: Looking again, it means  the returned record had `NULL` for that field.

Comment: But since you want time, I updated the code to show it, if it's available.

Comment: I just need to change the format to display in 12 hour format.

Comment: h:mm:ss tt this is what I needed to change :) thank you again

Comment: It is my understanding that the connection is returned to the pool when connection.Close() is called. As far as reusing the same connection object (not an open connection) is this deep knowledge that I need to take on faith or can I read somewhere about this messing up connection pooling.